# Error icon is displayed on the project name on eclipse

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins

I'm doing Jenkins and Maven integration. I was getting error message stating "No compiler is provided in this environment while running Maven build". One of the solution  is to add following plugins in POM.xml. :

```
 <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                      <configuration>
                         <verbose>true</verbose>
                         <fork>true</fork>
                         <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                    </configuration> 
                 </plugin>
```

After adding this plugin I'm able to build maven without any compiler error, but error sign is displayed on the project name. Now if I execute testng.xml file I'm getting error "TestNG by default disables loading DTD from unsecured Urls. If you need to explicitly load the DTD from a http url, please do so by using the JVM argument [-Dtestng.dtd.http=true]   at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.resolveEntity" , so I'm adding "-Dtestng.dtd.http=true"in VM argument. After adding I'm able to run script through testng.xml. Is there any permanent solution to this JVM issue also. Am I doing any thing wrong? Because my next step will be executing these test cases through Jenkins.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcQZb.png

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on your project and then do a update project configuration to see if that helps ?

Comment: Error sign vanished after updating the Project...Thanks!!!

Comment: I added the same as an answer so that the question gets closed. Please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Please right click on your project, and choose update project configuration. That should fix the problem.